# Pass array data inside value="" separated with ':' using AJAX/JSON | PHP, HTML

Tags: php, html, sql, json, ajax

Is it possible to pass data in aray using AJAX/JSON? Like `".$row['departmentname'].":".$row['jobposition'].":".$row['deptcode']."`?

This is the sample code.

```
if(sqlsrv_num_rows($query) > 0) {
        while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
          $emp=$row['empno'];
      $empno = str_pad(++$emp,7,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);

echo "<option value='".$row['departmentname'].":".$row['jobposition'].":".$row['deptcode']."".$empno."'>".$row['departmentname']." : ".$row['jobposition']."</option>";
        }
      }
```

I understand that this can work using AJAX, but I don't know how to set it up for array that is only separated with ":"

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#accounttype").change(function() {
    var accounttype = $(this).val();
    if(accounttype != "") {
      $.ajax({
        url:"earnings_amendment-employee_select_title.php",
        data:{accounttitleselector:accounttype},
        type:'POST',
        success:function(response) {
          var resp = $.trim(response);
          $("#accounttitleselector").html(resp);
        }
      });
    }
    else {
      $("#accounttitleselector").html("<option value=''>------- Select --------</option>");
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: yes its possible, if you want the input intact on the front end, its your choice, then you can separate them in PHP when they arrive there, then simply `$values = explode(':', $_POST['accounttitleselector']);` on the backend

Comment: or you can `.split()` on frontend too, and access it on PHP like any other array, the choice is yours

Comment: @Ghost, it will stay as it is? ill just ````explode()```` it, correct?

Comment: @Ghost, I'm using the ````"<option value='".$row['departmentname'].":".$row['jobposition'].":".$row['deptcode']."".$empno."'>"```` as new SQL filter for another php page

Comment: just treat it like any normal string, if its just a string inside the option value, `accounttype` should contain the value and sending it in PHP side should have it like any normal string. then explode if that's what you need to do

Comment: @Ghost, I'm sorry, I'm confused, how will I set it to as a filter? How will I set ````.$row['departmentname'].```` as ````$departmentname````, ````$row['jobposition']```` as ````$jobposition```` after I did ````$values = explode(':', $_POST['accounttitleselector']);````? I understand that ````$_POST['accounttitleselector'])```` will hold all the data inside ````value=""````, my question is how will I designate it?

Comment: after exploding it, then apply those pieces that you have and make your filter based on exploded string. normally you would use them on your query. but for me ideally, you're better off having multiple select dropdown boxes to have a better fine tuned filter if that's what you're after. im not sure why you squeeze every type of filter inside one option value. usually each kind of filters are separated on their own dropdown box

Comment: So, like ````$departmentname=$values[0];```` and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the row data in new array results and return the results in json format using json_encode

```
  if(sqlsrv_num_rows($query) > 0) {
        while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
          $emp=$row['empno'];
      $empno = str_pad(++$emp,7,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);

$array[] ="<option value='".$row['departmentname'].":".$row['jobposition'].":".$row['deptcode']."".$empno."'>".$row['departmentname']." : ".$row['jobposition']."</option>";
        }
      }

echo json_encode($array);
```

In jquery  after ajax success parse the response with JSON.parse(), and the data becomes a JavaScript object.

```
 //use each loop to get the option data from response
 success:function(response) {
      var data = JSON.parse(response);
            $("#accounttitleselector").html($.each(data, function(index, value) {
            value
        }))
    }
  });
```

Comment: I'll try this one, I'll keep you posted. Thank you!